# NullPointerException - check null on class

Tags: java, reflection

How to know the Employees.class is null or not using Java Relection?

Example Class: Employees.class

Problem:

- employees.getName();
- value getName is Mikel
- employees is null
- if employess != null is TRUE.
- this class already 'new Employees()'

Employees.Class

```
public class Employees{

private Long id;<br>
private String kodStuff;<br>
private String Name;<br>

//Getter and Setter<br>
}
```

Example Process Method:

```
public void check(){
    Employees employees = new Empoyees;
    employees.setName("Mikel");
    employees.setKodStuff("KL370");
    //employees not save yet and process redirect check value of Name wuth return boolean
    Boolean empty = checkName(employees);

}

public boolean checkName(Employees employees){
    boolean notNull = false;
    if(employees !=null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(employees.getName())){ // this is line 11
        notNull = true;
    }
    return notNull;
}
```

Throws exception at line no '11':

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How can i check null exception during process on line no.11?

Comment: "How to know the Employees.class is null". It isn't. The result of `A.class` is a `Class<A>` for any class `A`. This part of your title and your question has no relationship to the rest of it. The code you posted cannot possibly throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Must be something else. StringUtils is of apache? Otherwise check its implementation. `check` creates a new Employees, maybe remove `employees.` there so it sets the current employees.

Comment: @EJP - Right. Unless he has `employees ==null` (assuming he "mistyped" it correctly here)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if `employees.getName()` is null or not by doing:
`employees.getName() != null`